# Python re.match не работает

Tags: python

```
import re
newpayload = "(select(TEST)>64,0)"
result = re.match('\>[0-9]*\,', newpayload)
print(result)
print(re.sub('\>[0-9]*\,', '>99,', newpayload))
```

Вот пример кода, требуется достать цифру 64, но match ничего не находит, хотя sub заменяет все правильно! В чем магия ? Одна функция работает другая нет хотя регулярка одна и также.

Вот вывод программы :

```
None
(select(TEST)>99,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `match` всегда ищет строго с начала строки. Если шаблон идёт не в самом начале, то `match` его не найдёт. Для поиска внутри строки используйте `search`:

```
result = re.search('\>[0-9]*\,', newpayload)
```